# request.session['_csrf_token'] and meta tag csrf_token doesn't match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, csrf, faye

I have implemented real-time chat using websockets with Faye in Rails 4.2

Right now I can publish a message to channels using curl like:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/faye -d message={"channel":"/mychannel", "data": "my message"}'
```

To prevent this, I followed the guide http://faye.jcoglan.com/security/csrf.html

But client always got 401 error

```
[,…]
0: {id: "8l", channel: "/meta/handshake", error: "401::Access denied", successful: false, version: "1.0",…}
advice: {reconnect: "handshake"}
channel: "/meta/handshake"
error: "401::Access denied"
id: "8l"
successful: false
supportedConnectionTypes: ["long-polling", "cross-origin-long-polling", "callback-polling", "websocket", "eventsource",…]
version: "1.0"
```

I also debug token variables inside `CsrfProtection` extension. They always differ.

```
Started POST "/faye" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-20 02:53:59 +0600
session_token: "nICoUB0sDiwmNqbRpr1kUM7LtyBybCiddThnZceU7UI="
message_token: "PO5gD5tPwVMZifrUCsk8xnJXUIRZkhOU/vQ+ujbmQAugbshfhmPPfz+/XAWsdFiWvJznpCv+OwmLzFnf8XKtSQ=="
```

Why they differ and how do I implement csrf protection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method from Rails code may help: [token validation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e7feaff70f13b56a0507e9f4dfaf3ebc361cb8e6/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L276)

Idea: on the page you have Base64 encoded value and you need to decode it

Comment: It turned out that Faye Security docs a bit old. As @faron said, on the page I have base64 encoded value of csrf token. So I just added some additional logic to decode that string and compare with `request.session['_csrf_token']` only after that.